# MULTE en NODEJS y EXPRESS no puedo desarmar el array

Tags: nodejs, multer

por que no puedo desarmar el array de multer para obtener el path de cada foto utilizando la función "any" de multer el array que me da es el siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "fieldname": "foto1",
    "originalname": "ExitoRF.png",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/png",
    "destination": "upload",
    "filename": "efb12980-61af-483c-b91f-368dfd753355.png",
    "path": "upload/efb12980-61af-483c-b91f-368dfd753355.png",
    "size": 683625
  },
  {
    "fieldname": "foto2",
    "originalname": "Captura de pantalla_2019-08-07_11-36-50.png",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/png",
    "destination": "upload",
    "filename": "7c149682-09fc-438c-ac40-82928cf87c73.png",
    "path": "upload/7c149682-09fc-438c-ac40-82928cf87c73.png",
    "size": 265577
  },
  {
    "fieldname": "foto3",
    "originalname": "Captura de pantalla_2019-08-12_18-42-25.png",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/png",
    "destination": "upload",
    "filename": "936dcd9f-fab8-4429-9620-8e977b8d25a1.png",
    "path": "upload/936dcd9f-fab8-4429-9620-8e977b8d25a1.png",
    "size": 663554
  },
  {
    "fieldname": "foto4",
    "originalname": "Captura de pantalla_2019-08-15_20-34-51.png",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/png",
    "destination": "upload",
    "filename": "01a8bc76-954b-4bc8-9770-d25ad59de4b8.png",
    "path": "upload/01a8bc76-954b-4bc8-9770-d25ad59de4b8.png",
    "size": 822206
  }
]
```

> intente pasarlo a una const XXX=req.files pero todo lo que intento me da error .
>   desde ya gracias

Comment: `const arr = req.files; arr.forEach((x) => { console.log(x.originalname) });`

Comment: gracias a Rimuru Tempest avance y con : app.post('/multipleFiles', upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
    const file = req.files.forEach((x) => {
        const aa=x.path

        console.log(aa)

    }); logro sacar los uploads/FunOfHeuristic_Captura de pantalla_2019-11-03_18-06-33.png
uploads/FunOfHeuristic_Captura de pantalla_2019-11-03_18-09-39.png
uploads/FunOfHeuristic_Captura de pantalla_2019-11-03_18-09-53.png
uploads/FunOfHeuristic_Captura de pantalla_2019-11-03_18-20-43.png --esto me muestra los 5 path pero sigo sin pode manejarlos individualmente el File[0] no me funciona

Comment: Al decir manejarlos individualmente, te refieres obtener los datos(nombre, tamaño, extensión) al momento de subir un archivo?

Comment: si si entonces asi podria guardar la ubicación de cada foto en una Base de Datos

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres hacer, simplemente basta hacer la consulta de inserción a tu base de datos desde el `forEach`.

Supongamos que la ruta `/multipleFiles` es la ruta de subida de la datos de cada imagen, entonces tu código tendría que verse así:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

app.post('/multipleFiles', (req, res) => {
  var files = req.files;
  con.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    files.forEach((file) => {
      var sql = `INSERT INTO customers (originalname, encoding, mimetype, filename, path, size) VALUES ('${file.originalname}', '${file.encoding}', '${file.mimetype}', '${file.filename}', '${file.path}', '${file.size}')`;
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: me da un error:/opt/lampp/htdocs/testMulter/fileUpload-master/fileUpload_be/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^     ///ademas mi base de datos es asi://nombre/pathFoto1/pathFoto2/pathFoto3/// con un console.log me alcanza yo después ya lo subo a la base de datos